# traverse linklist using reference not working

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to make a queue list and I am passing reference of link list and its not working and giving error.

> In function 'void insertDataToQueue(Node**, int)':|
>    request for member 'next' in '* temp', which is of pointer type 'Node* {aka node*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

```
 void insertDataToQueue(Node **queueList, int burstTime){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->burstTime = burstTime;
    newNode->next = NULL;

if(queueList == NULL){
    *queueList = newNode;
}
else{
    Node **temp = queueList;
    while(*temp != NULL)
        temp = *temp->next;
}
}
```

Comment: member access has higher precendence than dereference, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: so how can i traverse this list ?

Comment: For what purpose are you writing a datastructure (that already exists in `namespace std`)?

Comment: I would advise not using pointer-to-pointer parameters (I don't think I've ever had a valid case for using one), instead learn about passing by reference, it makes the syntax much simpler and clearer

Comment: Has your question been resolved, by any answer ? If yes, consider to accept answer which resolves your issue. If no, feel free to ask more precision or any thing else

Comment: i did it .. just now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
*temp->next;
```

is parsed as

```
*(temp->next);
```

because [`->` has higher precedence than `*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), if you want to first dereference and then access the member you can use brackets:

```
(*temp)->next;
```

Comment: But `temp` is `Node **`. I think he has to be declared like this : `Node *temp = *queueList`

Comment: @Garf365 tbh I am lost once there is more than one `*`. Just not used to this stuff anymore since I realized that one can write C++ without pointers. I tried to concentrate the answer to the line that was asked for, it might be not the only error

Comment: I just mention that because, with your answer, this line  `temp = (*temp)->next;` produces an error, because temp is `Node**` and `(*temp)->next;` is `Node*`

Comment: @Garf365 i want to access the real list using temp variable and at the end i want to the newNode so i it should added to real list. can you help me with that pls ?

Comment: @AnkitBaid use `std::queue` or whichever container fits best.

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over whole list, just a simple pointer to `Node` is enough :

```
void insertDataToQueue(Node **queueList, int burstTime){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->burstTime = burstTime;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(queueList == NULL) {
        *queueList = newNode;
    }
    else {
        Node *temp = *queueList;
        // Find last element, ie element who "next" field is NULL
        while(temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        // Make last element to point to new element
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

---

Now, without any link, I suppose (and I hope) is only for learning aspect. Because C++ as every container you need. For exemple, you have `std::list` or `std::queue` who are linked list. For production code, prefer using it instead of developping by yourself.